# Auctex's C-c C-c issue with latexmk

Tags: auctex, latexmk

This is my Emacs information.

```
GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0, NS apple-appkit-1344.72)
 of 2015-02-16
```

I installed Auctex 11.88.2 with `package-install`.

When I open the main tex, and C-c C-c it, I got `Command: (default latexmk)`. Enter it to see `latexmk: problems after [0] pages`.

I tried `pdflatex` from the `Command: (default latexmk)`, I have [No match].

I checked that `latexmk main.tex` to get the correct pdf. Here are my questions.

- Q1: Why the `latexmk` does not work on AucTex? If I have to give the main latex source, how to do that? How to see the error log in AucTeX?
- Q2: How to set `C-c C-c` to prompt `pdflatex` not `latexmk`?

Comment: Did you setup `latexmk` in AUCTeX?  How?  It's not present by default, so you should explain what you did.  In addition, after compiling what's the content of the output buffer you get with `C-c C-l`?

Comment: @giordano: I didn't do any setup/change for AucTeX. It's in its raw state after the installation. `C-c C-1` is undefined for my AucTeX.

Comment: In vanilla AUCTeX there is no `latexmk` command, so it's impossible you can run it without doing anything.  `C-c C-l` shows the output log.  At this point I must ask you: are you sure you are using AUCTeX?  In the menu you should have a TeX or LaTeX entry, the last item in it is "Report AUCTeX bug".

Comment: Ah, in order to compile with `pdflatex` you should write `LaTeX` (case insensitive).

Comment: Maybe he installed Emacs with a starter package, there are some. @prosseek: Can you search for an init file or something like ".emacs"? To make sure, start Emacs with `emacs -q` from the command line and you will notice that you can not start latexmk via C-c C-c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that I have some messed up configuration setup.
This page (http://www.stefanom.org/setting-up-a-nice-auctex-environment-on-mac-os-x/) shows how to get correct AUCTeX configuration for Mac OS X. This page (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899845/emacs-synctex-skim-how-to-correctly-set-up-syncronization-none-of-the-exi) also helped.

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda ()
  (push
    '("latexmk" "latexmk -pdf %s" TeX-run-TeX nil t
      :help "Run latexmk on file")
    TeX-command-list)))
(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook '(lambda () (setq TeX-command-default "latexmk")))
```

I also needed a ~/.latexmkrc

```
$pdflatex = 'pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 %O %S';
$pdf_previewer = 'open -a skim';
$clean_ext = 'bbl rel %R-blx.bib %R.synctex.gz';
```

I also had to include the path to the `latexmk` in the configuration file. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20015930/auctex-and-emacs-on-mac)

```
(let ((my-path (expand-file-name "/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-darwin")))
    (setenv "PATH" (concat my-path ":" (getenv "PATH")))
    (add-to-list 'exec-path my-path))
```

After all these changes, it works fine.